# AES keyfile size

Tags: encryption, openssl, aes, file-encryption

I would like to encrypt files using a key file instead of a password. What I would do is:

1) Generate X random bits using `openssl rand X > mykey`

2) `openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -in secretfile -out secretfile.enc -k mykey`

Is this secure? How many bits should the key file should be?

Comment: If you want a *password* file (NOT a key) use `-kfile` or `-pass file:` with *text* in the file (most simply `opensssl rand -hex`) per the man pages https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/apps/enc.html https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/apps/openssl.html . Given `enc`'s moderate stretching about 90 bits of entropy should be enough but you can do more if you like. If you really want a *key* in a file, commandline `openssl` doesn't do that, you'll have to write a program or wrap it in something like a perl or python script, and an aes-256 key must be 256 bits exactly.